# Get nth element of every array in an array in JavaScript efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays

`a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`

I want b such that it is equal to `[2,2,2]`, which is `a[:][1]`, i.e. second element of every array in a. I don't want to use a for loop.

I wanted a javascript equivalent of Python's numpy's `a[:,1]` which outputs `[2,2,2]`, if possible.

Please note that I do know that I can iterate through every array in `a` to get the second element.

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant tags (python, numpy) just because you mention those words in your question.

Comment: @DYZ My bad, I'm new.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best you can get probably is `map`:

```js
var a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];

console.log(
  a.map(x => x[1])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];
console.log(a.map(function(value,index) { return value[1]; }));
//[2, 2, 2] is the output
```